# Trying to get information from multiple text files to display in a website table

Tags: php, foreach, html-table, text-files

I have been trying to figure out how to pull information from multiple text files inside a single folder to show neatly in a table on a webpage, there are about 3 or so lines that I need to clean up and show.  The number of text files will vary.

The lines that I need to pull from the text files start with:

```
name = 
category = 
source =
```

Some examples of what will be in text files:

example1.conf:

```
name = unique name1

information I do not want
more information I do not want

category = unique category1

source = https://unique-source1.com

a lot of information I do not want
```

example2.conf

```
information I do not want

name = unique name2

more information I do not want

category = unique category2

source = https://unique-source2.com

a lot of information I do not want
```

example3.conf

```
name = unique name3

category = unique category3

information I do not want

source = https://unique-source3.com

a lot of information I do not want
```

They need to show something like this:

```
 ____________________________________________
|    Name    |    Category    |    Source    |
|------------|----------------|--------------|
|unique name1|unique category1|unique source1|
|unique name2|unique category2|unique source2|
|unique name3|unique category3|unique source3|
|unique name4|unique category4|unique source4|
|unique name5|unique category5|unique source5|
|unique name6|unique category6|unique source6|
 --------------------------------------------
```

This code works to grab one of the items at a time and list them in a single row:

```
<?php
$path_to_check = '';
$needle = 'name = ';

foreach(glob($path_to_check . '*.conf') as $filename)
{  
  foreach(file($filename) as $fli=>$fl)
  {
    if(strpos($fl, $needle)!==false)
    {
      echo preg_replace(array('/name = /'), 
        '', $fl,);
        echo "<br />";
    }
  }
} 
?>
```

For it to grab the other items, I would need to change $needle = '`name =`'; and ('/`name =`/') to match the names I need.

I had thought I had enough information in my question to explain what I needed, however as a couple people pointed out, it looks like I did not, so I updated the post just in case anybody else needs help with this one.  Hopefully it clears up the questions they had.

Comment: What is the error or what you want , kindly specify .

Comment: Everything I have tried so far to add tables breaks it.  As far as what I want, I need to have multiple sorted results from multiple text files in a table.

Comment: Can you please be more specific .....your comment does not clear anything.

Comment: I really do not know how to be more specific than what is in the main post, it explains exactly what I am needing.

Comment: Add an example Text file (just a few lines) and what code you have tried to seperate those lines into its seperate parts.

Comment: The 3 lines I listed above are formatted just like they would be in the text file, name = unique names
category = unique category's
source = unique sources

Comment: As far as the code to separate them into tables, that is the question I am asking.  Nothing I have tried has even come close to working.  I have never had a need to use the foreach function, so I am unfamiliar with how to customize it.

Comment: I am still unsure as to what your input is, does each text file only have 3 lines? and if not how do you know which unique names, etc.. go on each row of the table?

Comment: It is a foreach loop, each file will have a different name, category, and source.  If you look at the code provided at the bottom, it shows how I pull the name from each file and post them.  There is other lines of text in the files, currently I only need those 3.  The part in the lines that will always be the same are name = ,
category = ,
source = .

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, there may be a cleaner way, but this at least works:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-73oq{border-color:#000000;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-73oq">Name</th>
    <th class="tg-73oq">Category</th>
    <th class="tg-73oq">Source</th>
  </tr>
    <?php
    $path_to_check = '';
    $needle1 = 'name = ';
    $needle2 = 'category = ';
    $needle3 = 'source = ';
    foreach(glob($path_to_check . '*.conf') as $filename)
    {  
     foreach(file($filename) as $fli=>$fl)
      {
        if(strpos($fl, $needle1)!==false)
        {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo '<td class="tg-73oq">'.preg_replace(array('/name = /','/\(RAM \>.+\)/'),'', $fl,)."</td>";
        }
      }
      foreach(file($filename) as $fli=>$f2)
      {
        if(strpos($f2, $needle2)!==false)
        {
          echo '<td class="tg-73oq">'.preg_replace(array('/category = /'),'', $f2,)."</td>";
        }
      }
      foreach(file($filename) as $fli=>$f3)
      {
        if(strpos($f3, $needle3)!==false)
        {
          echo '<td class="tg-73oq">'.'<a href='.preg_replace(array('/source = /'),'',$f3,).'>'.'Source'.'</a>'."</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
      }
    } 
    ?>
</table>
</body>
```